# Missing required parameter for [Route: cursos.show] [URI: cursos/{curso}] [Missing parameter: curso]

Tags: laravel-8

El error me apareció al instalarle `tailwindcss`, después de crear el blog me salió ese error y la ruta `{{route('cursos.show', $curso->slug)}}` no me lo toma en cuenta ya le vueltas al codigo y no veo el error al codigo. Este es el código de mi índex donde hago mi lista y le pongo una etiqueta  y la ruta donde esta la vista

```
<ul>
   @foreach ($cursos as $curso)
       <li>
          <a href="{{route('cursos.show', $curso->slug)}}">{{$curso->name}}</a>
       </li>
   @endforeach
</ul>
```

Mi controlador es:

```
public function show(Curso $curso)
{
   return view('cursos.show', compact('curso'));
}
```

Este es mi Model:

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}
```

Esta  es mi tabla de migracion

```
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('cursos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->text('descripcion');
            $table->text('categoria');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Este mi factory:

```
  public function definition()
    {
        $name = $this->faker->sentence();
        return [
            //Poner los atributos de mi tabla
            'name' => $name,
            'slug' => Str::slug($name, '-'),  Esta parte hago es donde hago el la url amigable separado por -
            'descripcion'=>$this->faker->paragraph(),
            'categoria'=>$this->faker->randomElement(['Desarrollo Web', 'Diseño Web'])
        ];
    }
```

Comment: Según entiendo, la ruta cursos recibe un parámetro obligatorio y este no se está pasando al controlador a través de la ruta. Si no me equivoco, cuando son controladores tipo resources y creados desde los comandos artisan, estos crean ese tipo de estructura. ¿Estás seguro que cuando haces `Curso $curso` y haces un return de esa variable te muestra algo? También sospecho es en la forma de usar el helper `route` creo que se usa `route('name.route', ['id' => $var])`

Comment: me ayudo mucho tu comentario revise bien mi Model Curso  gracias

Comment: No es nada, para eso estamos. No se te olvide editar tus preguntas para evitar confusiones.

Answer (score 0):

el problema esta también al hacer una url amigable para no modificar el Model  copie el código donde laravel identifica que la url por medio del id que es este

```
  public function getRouteKeyName()
  {
      return getKeyName();
  }
```

y te muestra la url en la pagina que uno se encuentra ejemplo blog.test/curso/41

y yo `cree un model llamado Curso` que tome mi slug para hacer la url amigable ejemplo blog.tes/curso/laravel-8 y tome ese código y lo copie en model Curso para que tome mi slug creado en mi factory

```
  public function getRouteKeyName()
  {
      return 'slug';
  }
```